# Moving jquery sortable to empty nested list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've created a simple nested sortable list.  I'm able to move parent list (with their children).  I'm able to move a child within a parent list, or from a parent list to another parent list as long as there are already children in that parent list.  However, I am not able to move a child to a parent list that has no children.

For example, I can move Sub A within Parents Three and Five, but cannot move Sub A to Parent One, Two or Four even though I have set up an empty UL with the sublist class.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sortable Sandbox</h1>

<ul class='mainlist'>
    <li><span class='mov_handle'></span>One
        <ul class="sublist"></ul>
    </li>
    <li><span class='mov_handle'></span>Two
        <ul class="sublist"></ul>
    </li>
    <li><span class='mov_handle'></span>Three
        <ul class="sublist">
            <li><span class='mov_handle'></span>Sub A</li>
            <li><span class='mov_handle'></span>Sub B</li>
            <li><span class='mov_handle'></span>Sub C</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span class='mov_handle'></span>Four
        <ul class="sublist"></ul>
    </li>
    <li><span class='mov_handle'></span>Five
        <ul class="sublist">
            <li><span class='mov_handle'></span>Sub D</li>
            <li><span class='mov_handle'></span>Sub E</li>
            <li><span class='mov_handle'></span>Sub F</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('ul.mainlist').sortable({
          handle: '.mov_handle',
        connectWith: 'ul.mainlist'
    });
    $('ul.sublist').sortable({
          handle: '.mov_handle',
        connectWith: 'ul.sublist',
          dropOnEmpty: 1
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a very simple solution... You need to have at least some height to the UL.sublist elements or there really isn't anything to drop on. Try adding the below style to your demo...

```
ul.sublist {
  min-height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I had a feeling it was something simple!